# perl daemon Proc::Daemon::Init issue with DBI

Tags: perl, daemon

I have a program as mentioned below:

```
use DBI;
use Proc::Daemon;
Proc::Daemon::Init;


my $continue = 1; $SIG{TERM} = sub { $continue = 0 };
while ($continue) {

        my $db=DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:xx;user=root;password=xxx');
        my $sth=$db->prepare("select * from  cpu_mem_calls ");
            $sth->execute();
         while (my @row=$sth->fetchrow_array()){
        $x=$row[0]+200;
        $y=$row[1]+200;

                 my $db_test=DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:xx;user=root;password=xxx');
                         my $sth=$db->prepare("insert into  cpu_mem_calls values ($x,$y,'2011-03-21 17:19:00')");
                $sth_test->execute();
                        $sth_test->finish();
                        $db_test->disconnect();
$sth->finish();
$db->disconnect();
sleep(5);

        }
```

I can insert values into  database  when I use `Proc::Daemon::Init` module + `DBI`  but when I want to select some values from database it won't work. It won't return any value. What is the real issue in this? Does DBI have any issue in running with `Proc::Daemon::Init`?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue...I was trying to read some IP's from a file...as its a daemon it cannot read from the file..I put all the things in an array and everything started working fine